# How can I extract a substring from multiple lines from a file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, split, enumerate

I have a file that contains thousands of lines, and in the file, there are some lines like:

```
Line 115463: 08:59:25.106   08:59:24.992877 ASDF_IIS_CFGDB  GenMod  Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event2f, DIR = 13)    rrc_UlUtranMsg.c (../../../HEDGE/UL3/ASDF/UtranMsg/Uplink/Code/Src) 987 
Line 236362: 08:59:28.647   08:59:28.597827 ASDF_IIS_CFGDB  GenMod  Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Eventab, DIR = 1) rrc_UlUtranMsg.c (../../../HEDGE/UL3/ASDF/UtranMsg/Uplink/Code/Src) 934 
Line 324964: 08:59:40.456   08:59:40.403644 ASDF_IIS_CFGDB  GenMod  Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Eventac, DIR = 1) rrc_UlUtranMsg.c (../../../HEDGE/UL3/ASDF/UtranMsg/Uplink/Code/Src) 934 
Line 341172: 08:59:40.659   08:59:40.616565 ASDF_IIS_CFGDB  GenMod  Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Eventfb, DIR = 13)    rrc_UlUtranMsg.c (../../../HEDGE/UL3/ASDF/UtranMsg/Uplink/Code/Src) 987 
Line 373186: 08:59:41.174   08:59:41.104755 ASDF_IIS_CFGDB  GenMod  Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event2f, DIR = 1) rrc_UlUtranMsg.c (../../../HEDGE/UL3/ASDF/UtranMsg/Uplink/Code/Src) 934 
Line 480217: 08:59:44.481   08:59:44.389453 ASDF_IIS_CFGDB  GenMod  Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Eventx1, DIR = 1) rrc_UlUtranMsg.c (../../../HEDGE/UL3/ASDF/UtranMsg/Uplink/Code/Src) 934 
Line 505424: 08:59:44.777   08:59:44.701709 ASDF_IIS_CFGDB  GenMod  Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event1a, DIR = 1) rrc_UlUtranMsg.c (../../../HEDGE/UL3/ASDF/UtranMsg/Uplink/Code/Src) 934
```

I only need to extract the substring

> '1a'

from

> 'SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event1a, DIR = 1)'

and so on.
So, basically, the two characters after '(Event'

And I need to store these in a list or somewhere else where I can use them.

How can I do this?

So far, I have tried the following code but it gives me some values mixed in:

```
events = []

for line in input_txt_file:
        if "Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS " not in line: continue
        parts = line.split('Event')
        event_temp = [0]
        for i,part in enumerate(parts):
            if part.endswith("Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS ("): event_temp[0] = parts[i+1].split(None,1)[0].split(',',2)[0]
            events.append(event_temp)

print events
```

The output I am getting is:

> [[0], [0], ['2f'], ['2f'], ['ab'], ['ab'], [0], [0], ['ac'], ['ac'], ['fb'], .......]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the line position is always fixed, Wayne's answer is the most efficient. If the position can vary a bit, this is a decent situation in which to use regex:

```
import re
events = []

for line in input_txt_file:
    match = re.search(r'SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS.*?Event(..)', line)
    if match:
        events.append(match.group(1))
```

This searches each line for `SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS`, followed by possibly some characters, followed by `Event` and then two more characters, and grabs those two characters.

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thanks.

Comment: is it `Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS` or just `SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS` that we are searching for?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre unclear, the OP uses it sometimes with the `Ta-` and sometimes without.

Comment: your answer is accepted. The OP will probably sort it out by him/herself.

Comment: It is 'Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS' in all occurrences, but the TA part is not that important as the rest of the string ('SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS') did not occur in my original text file without it. Even if I need it later, I'll probably tweak the expression a little bit and add it.
Thanks again @Amber. Can you suggest some good resources to learn about regular expressions in python, and regular expressions in general?

Answer (score 3):

If you know that it's always going to be in that position you can simply do:

```
hexes = [line[99:101] for line in file]
```

If there are lines that don't contain that text you can do:

```
hexes = [line[99:101] for line in file if 'Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS' in line]
```

Comment: The problem is, there are other lines in between these lines in the file too.

Comment: @uddinM there it is with a filter

Comment: Thanks.:-) I'll try it out in another similar program I'm working on.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this as a substring search using the `re` module, personally.

```python
import re

for line in input_txt_file:
    val = ''
    val = re.search('SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS \(Event(.+?), DIR\)', line).group(1)
    print(val)
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for regex here: just split according to `Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event` and take 2 first letters of the 2nd field if there's one:

```
events=[]
for line in input_txt_file:
    toks = line.split("Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event")
    if len(toks)>1:
        events.append(toks[1][:2])
```

EDIT: found a cool one-liner equivalent:

```
events=[tok[:2] for line in input_txt_file for i,tok in enumerate(line.split("Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event")) if i==1]
```

Uses `enumerate` and tests if the index of the splitted item is 1: means there are at least 2 items. In that case, take 2 first chars from the token.

EDIT2: Amber has even better using `partition` to avoid the `enumerate` hack:

```
events=[t for t in (l.partition("Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event")[2] for l in input_txt_file) if t]
```

Comment: This is more efficient, but also brittle - if we're already assuming the position within the line might change, then the spacing may as well.

Comment: you're right. I was just proposing a non-regex solution. We don't know if the spacing may change. If it does, then why not the number of `_` chars too?

Comment: Your solution is perfectly fine - just pointing out the tradeoffs. :) In many cases the efficiency would win out.

Comment: thanks! I was not feeling attacked. It's just that I like to reply to open comments. I also know that there should be at least one non-regex solution if it's possible. It's too easy with regex :) something I read here: if you have a problem and you use regexes, then you have 2 problems. Doesn't really apply here, however, not willing to bash your good answer.

Comment: now I'm looking for a one-liner, but that's tougher :)

Comment: Well the main question is, what do you consider a one-liner? E.g. my solution could be written in one line, and Wayne's already is. :)

Comment: a one-liner using `split` only once to count _and_ to extract data. Found it. See my edit.

Comment: A slightly shorter version would be `events=[t for t in (l.partition("Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event")[2] for l in input_txt_file) if t]`

Comment: I never quite understood the `partition` function purpose. Very good.

Comment: In most cases I prefer to write it out as `pre, _, post = foo.partition()` but that's less useful for a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Short solution using `re.findall()` function:

```
# change to your actual file path
with open('./text_files/events.txt', 'r') as fh:
    l = re.findall(r'(?<=Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS \(Event)\w+', fh.read(), re.M)

print(l)
```

The output:

```
['2f', 'ab', 'ac', 'fb', '2f', 'x1', '1a']
```

Comment: What if there's other places in the file where the word 'Eventxx' where xx is the data i want occurs besides these lines?
I wanted to omit those occurrences and only use the ones which follow 'Ta-SNS__GENERATED_EVENTS (Event'